# Number Spinner with jQuery

Tags: jquery, numbers, spinner

I'm trying to create a simple number spinner, where you can click on + or - to change the value inside a div.

The code does not function in the way I would like it to. Right now, clicking on the `+` or `-` buttons does not change the value. What am I doing wrong?

My code is as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="minus">-</div>
<input type="text" id="num" value="0" />
<div class="plus">+</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

div.minus,
div.plus {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
   $(".plus").click(function(){
       var quantity = parseInt($("#num").val()) +1;
       $("#num").val(quantity);
       return false;
   });

  $(".minus").click(function(){
       var quantity = parseInt($("#num").val()) -1;
       if(quantity < 0) quantity = 0;
       $("#num").val(quantity);
       return false;
   });
```

A working example of the code can be found [here](http://codepen.io/itsthomas/pen/izqBf).

Comment: "*what am I doing wrong?*" - well, for a start you've confused a URL with actual code; that caution that you ignored? That was trying to help you get answers. Now, please, [edit] your question and post your [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code so that we can help.

Comment: Incidentally, to those answering: if you feel the question is worth answering then please salvage it: **[edit]** so that it can avoid deletion.

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://jqueryui.com/spinner/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to use `.html()` instead of `.val()` to get the `qty`. Also, since this came as a string, you needed to call `parseInt()` on it before doing math.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".plus").click(function(){
        var newQty = parseInt($(".qty").html()) + 1;
        $(".qty").html(newQty);
    });

    $(".minus").click(function(){
        var newQty = parseInt($(".qty").html()) - 1;
        if(newQty < 0)newQty = 0;
            $(".qty").html(newQty);
    });
```

});

Answer (score 1):

First off, I'm assuming you included jQuery on the page and just didn't reference it in the question. If you did not, make sure to do that.

Here is a fully working example of what you are trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/tdfm3bpp/

You had a couple of issues. First, you need `.html()`. instead of `.val()` to get the number value inside the div.

Second, the returned value of `.html()` is a string. You need to use `parseInt()` to first convert the string to an integer before doing the necessary addition or subtraction.

Final working code (from the jsFiddle) is as follows:

```
<div class="minus">-</div>
<div class="qty">1</div>
<div class="plus">+</div>
```

---

```
div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

div.minus,
div.plus {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".plus").click(function(){
    var newQty = (parseInt($(".qty").html()) + 1);
    $(".qty").html(newQty);
  });

  $(".minus").click(function(){
    var newQty = (parseInt($(".qty").html()) - 1);
    if(newQty < 0)newQty = 0;
    $(".qty").html(newQty);
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You did not include jQuery in the Pen.
2. You have use `.text ()` to extract the number from div instead of `.val()`.
3. You have to use `parseInt()` to parse the text into an integer.
4. You have to assign a new value, not `+=` to the newQty.

The follwing code and Pen have been fixed the aboves.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".plus").click(function(){
    $(".qty").text(parseInt(($(".qty").text())) + 1);
  });

  $(".minus").click(function(){
    $(".qty").text(Math.max(0, parseInt(($(".qty").text())) - 1));
  });
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Lvakr